# Does PostgreSQL support `unnest` as a column?

Tags: postgresql, array, computed-column, set-returning-functions

Does PostgreSQL document and support this behavior of the SRF `unnest()` as a computer/virtual column,

```
SELECT
  unnest(array_agg(id)) AS id
FROM foo
GROUP BY CUBE (a,b,c,d)
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

If I try to move the `unnest` to FROM there, I get

```
ERROR:  aggregate functions are not allowed in functions in FROM
LINE X: CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(array_agg(id)) AS id
```

You can create the test data to run against this, like this

```
CREATE TABLE foo AS
SELECT row_number() OVER (), *
FROM ( VALUES
  ( 'X', 'D', 'G', 'P' ),
  ( 'F', 'D', 'L', 'M' ),
  ( 'X', 'N', 'R', 'S' ),
  ( 'Y', 'I', 'W', 'Q' ),
  ( 'U', 'Z', 'E', 'H' )
) AS f(a,b,c,d);
```

What's a better way to write the above?

Is there anything less convoluted than,

```
SELECT k FROM (
  SELECT array_agg(id) AS x
  FROM foo
  GROUP BY CUBE (a,b,c,d)
  HAVING count(*) > 1
) AS t
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(x) AS k;
```

Comment: Nope, I think your solution is the standard way to express it. It definitely is convoluted.

Comment: Could you please explain what is the purpose of this code?